# what is the pythonic way to create a list combinations

Tags: python

Let's assume I have two lists:

```
list_one = [1A, 1B]
list_two = [2A]
```

How can I get a list containing pairs of words from both these arrays? To visualize:

```
answer = [1A-2A, 1B-2A]
```

I know I can do it using two `for` loops but is there a 'pythonic' way?

Comment: format your desired result properly please. Also quote your strings

Comment: I am still waiting for a day when I see the word *pythonic* in a dictionary. Or when my browser stops underlining it like it just did.

Answer (score 7):

You can simply use [`product` from `itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product).

```
from itertools import product

list_one = ['1A', '1B']
list_two = ['2A']

result = ['-'.join(sub) for sub in product(list_one, list_two)]
print(result)  # -> ['1A-2A', '1B-2A']
```

I do not think it gets any more *pythonic* than this.

---

Under the hood, `product(list_one, list_two)` generates tuples of the form `('1A', '2A')` which we simply `'-'.join()` to produce the desired result.